# Is Stream Chat API HIPAA and GDPR Compliant?

Tags: getstream-io

We are looking for a Chat SDK and need it to be both HIPAA and GDPR compliant. However I can't seem to find information on whether or not Stream is HIPAA/GDPR compliant on their website. Could someone answer this for me and/or point me to some documentation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for documentation around how these different SDKs are capable of stripping out [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) *automatically for you* or *preventing it from being stored/retrieved*?

Comment: HIPAA.  Not HIPPA.

Comment: Thanks @TomServo, I made the update. Are the downvotes due to the misspell? I feel like this is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream Chat is GDPR compliant and HIPPA ready. We have a GDPR DPA and a BAA that can be attached to enterprise contracts. If you'd like more information or want to explore options please reach out via our talk to an expert form on getstream.io. Thanks!